# sharepoint field value show undefined

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am learning sharepoint 2013. I am trying to show some data in web part. Below is my code

```
<script unselectable="on">
window.onload = function() {
  myFunction();
};
function myFunction() {
console.log("test");
$().SPServices
({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false, 
webURL: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite(),
listName: "Share Point List",
CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>", 
completefunc: function (xData, Status)
{
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() 
{
console.log(firstName);
var firstName = $(this).attr("ows_First_Name");
var lastName = $(this).attr("ows_Last_Name");
var gender = $(this).attr("ows_Gender");
var dateOfBirth = $(this).attr("ows_Date_of_Birth");
var email = $(this).attr("ows_Email");
var city = $(this).attr("ows_City");
var country = $(this).attr("ows_Country");
console.log(gender);
$("#myDataTable").append("<tr align='right'>" +
"<td>"+firstName+"</td>" +
"<td>"+lastName+"</td>" +
"<td>"+gender+"</td>" +
"<td>"+dateOfBirth+"</td>" +
"<td>"+email+"</td>" +
"<td>"+city+"</td>" +
"<td>"+country+"</td>" +  "</tr>"); 
});
}
});
}
</script>
```

For the fields name with single name like Email, Gender, City I get correct value but for field names with space like First Name, Last Name etc I get undefined value. What should be the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

Brother ...

Use the REST functionality, use ajax to read the whole item of a list and compare using .indexof <0 to check if there already that name.

First use ajax with the rest link to read all items. Crei a list of all the names, then do one for traversing the whole list and inside is an append in div camparando names.indexOf if (names [i]) <0 && names.indexOf (names [i])

Answer (score 0):

The problem with REST over SOAP (SP Services) is that REST can only be used on the site where the list resides.  If you want to get data from a list on another subsite or a parent site you can only do this with SOAP.